# How to pass a function pointer to overloaded member function as parameter

Tags: c++, code-generation, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

This is related to code generation.

I have a class `A` which is generated from model, in which I have two overloads of function `f` like below:

```
class A
{
  public:
    void f(int a){}
    void f(int a, int b){}
}
```

I then have a separate part of the system which is not generated from model, but written in hand crafted C++. Here I would like to access the function `f` on an object. From the model I can pass data to the hand crafted part of the system, but not the other way around, since the generated file is not available for compilation when I build my hand crafted code.

My idea is to pass a function pointer from the model to where I need it. This, as I have understood it so far, includes `static_cast` to solve the overload issue and then I can pass a pointer to the function as a parameter to some other hand crafted function.

The function used to pass the pointer to the hand crafted part of the system is declared like this (here `A` is not known):

```
void passPointer(int, void (*f)(int, int));
```

My cast and function call looks like:

```
handCraftedObject->passPointer(17, static_cast<void (A::*)(int, int)> (&A::f) );
```

My compilation error is:

```
:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'void (A::*)(int, int)' to 'void (*)(int, int)
```

I hope this doesn't mean i have to know the class `A` where the function passing the function pointer is declared. This is not possible in my system.

Comment: Function pointer is not the same as member (function) pointer, the second need an instance of class.

Comment: The method `A::f` has to become static, or you have to change signature...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member function pointer has different type than function pointer and cannot be converted to it. The simplest way is to use boost/std(C++11) `bind` and `function`.

```
void passPointer(int, const std::function<void(int, int)>&);
```

than just

```
handCraftedObject->passPointer
(
   17, std::bind(static_cast<void (A::*)(int, int)> (&A::f), std::ref(a_instance), 
   std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)
);
```

Also you cannot use boost/C++11, you can make function `f` `static`, then all will works fine.